# What can cause "Message from debugger: Terminated due to memory issue"

Tags: ios, memory

My app is sometimes crashing and the console says

`Message from debugger: Terminated due to memory issue`

Has anyone else experienced this and know some of what can cause this?  Here is what I have tried so far.

1. I have enabled Zombie Objects and it does not find anything.
2. This only happens on my iPhone and so I can't run the other Memory Management tools that only run on the simulator (ie Guard Malloc).
3. This only happens after a low memory warning.  It doesn't happen after every memory warning, just after some memory warnings.  When my app receives a memory warning, it clears out a number of caches and so my guess is that it is related to this.
4. In the simulator I simulated memory warnings and this never happened.
5. I thought that it might be related to a weak object so I added a symbolic break point on `objc_weak_error`.  I did get the debugger to stop one this break point once and I fixed the weak error, but it did not fix the "Terminated due to memory issue".
6. I though that maybe I wasn't freeing up enough memory, so I watched the total memory used by my app in Xcode and it never went over 50% of available memory.
7. My app is a mixture of Objective-C and Swift code.  It appears that this is coming from areas of my app that are written in Objective-C, but I am not 100% sure.

I would love to know if anyone else has experienced this issue and if so what you did to fix it.  I have looked at the other Stack Overlow issues on this and so far none of them have given me any extra insight to this problem.

Comment: My starting guess is that you're using too much memory somewhere.  If so, enabling Zombies will make it worse.  I'd try running Instruments using the Allocations tool (or maybe the Leaks tool) and see where large items, or many items, are being created.

Answer (score 1):

So one of my initial observations was wrong. I thought that my app never went above 50% of available memory (point 6 above).  I was wrong.  It did use up more memory and this error is coming because I did not release enough memory during the memory warning.